# On a C# Web Service can I find a unique thread ID or some ID for logging purposes?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, multithreading

I am running a Web Service in C# .NET 3.5.  I want to log various calls.  However since many users are hitting the same functions at once it is difficult to tell which log call belongs to which.

In a C++ life we used a thread Id.  What is the equivalent in C#?

I have tried

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
proc.Id;
```

However this gets me the same Id each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MS Ent Lib and their logger you can use the Tracer class to get some nice logging:

Example

```
public Output MyServiceMethod(Input input, string transactionId)
{
    using(new Tracer("MyServiceMethod: " + transactionId))
    {
        ... stuff ...
        return output;
    }
}
```

You can even nest Tracers. All logging within the using will have the string you give Tracer constructor as an extended property.

Answer (score 3):

Mayhaps Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
```

Also, since this is a web service, if the clients are coming from different IP Addresses, you could log that too which may well help with logging/diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some logging frameworks such as log4net, you will notice that thread ID is logged automatically for you.

It is very easy to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ASP.NET Health Monitoring. See [ASP.NET Health Monitoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx). The events that it logs by default contain more information than you probably want:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Date:          2/12/2009 12:57:14
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Laptop
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2/12/2009 12:57:14 
Event time (UTC): 2/12/2009 17:57:14 
Event ID: b08e9d3be7364690a660254dc0a29b6d 
Event sequence: 5 
Event occurrence: 4 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: bba4cebc-1-128789349683310000 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Users\John Saunders\Documents\MVP\projects\WebServices\GeneralSoln\WebService1\ 
    Machine name: LAPTOP 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 11560 
    Process name: WebDev.WebServer.exe 
    Account name: Laptop\John Saunders 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: MissingMethodException 
    Exception message: Method not found: 'Void System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.EventLogger.UnsafeLogEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType, System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.EventLogCategory, System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.EventLogEventId, Boolean, System.String[])'. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:5305/Enumerations.asmx 
    Request path: /Enumerations.asmx 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: Laptop\John Saunders 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 4 
    Thread account name: Laptop\John Saunders 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareDelegate(Delegate d)
   at System.AppDomain.add_UnhandledException(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler value)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HookADUnhandledExceptionEvent()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.OnEnsureInitialized(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.PartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.SafeEnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details: 

Event Xml:
```